# Any difference between a SSH user, SFTP user, cPanel user, etc?

Tags: linux, security, ssh, sftp

I've recently disabled root access on my server and enabled sudo for my user. However I also use this user account for SFTP and logging into cPanel. Is there any security issue with this? By default I always used the same user account for both SFTP and cPanel, now also having it as a sudo user I'm not sure if this is correct. Am I supposed to be using a separate user for SSH, separate user for SFTP and separate user for cPanel? Or is my current setup not an issue? Thank you.

Edit: Heh, is this really such a bad question? I'm not sure it just didn't feel right to be using the same user for various activities. Well I'm glad I asked to confirm that there shouldn't be too much worries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally am using the same user for everything. Ensure that the user has a strong password (8+ characters, alphanumeric and symbols). Also ensure that the computer you are using for SSH stays malware free.

You should install something like fail2ban, logwatch, or CSF/LFD, which give you knowledge of any possible brute forces and also help block the offending user.

An extra bit of advice: Use SFTP built into the SSH server instead of an FTP server, or FTP + SSL (FTPS - not to be confused with SFTP !). The Older plain FTP protocol is insecure, as the login and password are transmitted as clear text over the network.

Comment: Thanks, I did actually stop using plain FTP a while ago, but I just use FTP as a term in a general sense. I guess I should get used to saying SFTP more. :) Hmm, how about if say my host needs terminal access, should I create a separate user or just let him use my account?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer (to your first question, at least) is "maybe".

UNIX has a concept of users - these are the "system" users that you'll see listed in `/etc/passwd`. Some programs defer to the system for authentication - and thus share the same set of users - and some programs don't.

(FTP servers *often* do use the system's users, but certainly don't *have* to; cPanel *probably* has its own set).